# Android: restart CursorLoader on content changed

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader, contentobserver

I'm using the **LoaderManager** and the **CursorLoader** to load data from my **ContentProvider** to the GUI in an async way. Everything works fine. But I wonder how to restart the loader once the content of the ContentProvider has changed? As far I as I researched, the CursorLoader should do that automatically, but in my case it does not! So, should I register a content observer and restart the LoaderManager again?

**Note:** The ContentProvider is implemented correctly. For instance, if a new item is inserted, I'm calling ContentProvider.notifyChange(...) with the main URI and the URI for the newly inserted item. For ContentObservers this works fine.

```
public class MyFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (isDetached())
            return null;

        Uri queryUri = MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = this.getProjection();
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = null;

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), queryUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // ToDo: display the content (in this case it's not a ListView but a Google Map with markers)

        // Remark: I'm using the data/cursor only, but I'm not holding the loader!
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // ToDo: clear/remove all markers from the map
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your query method from your provider check if is setted a notification uri in your cursor before to return it.

```
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        int match = mUriMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor;
        switch (match) {
            case ROUTE_POSITIONS:
                cursor = db.query(DatabaseContract.PositionEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                cursor.setNotificationUri(contentResolver, DatabaseContract.PositionEntry.CONTENT_URI);
                break;
            // do more cases ....
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknow uri: " + uri);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

after in your activity you can define an async task to load data in map

```
private class LoadMarkers extends AsyncTask<Cursor, MarkerOptions, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Cursor... params) {
        Cursor data = params[0];
        LatLng latLng = null;
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            double latitude = data.getDouble(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.PositionEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LATITUDE));
            double longitude = data.getDouble(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.PositionEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LONGITUDE));
            String date = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.PositionEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UPDATETIME));
            latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().title(date).position(latLng);
            publishProgress(markerOptions);
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading...");
        }
        int count = data .getCount();
        return count + " points";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(MarkerOptions... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = values[0];
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mTextView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

and execute when a new query is ready

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "data loaded: " + data.getCount() + " points");
    new LoadMarkers().execute(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That's the way I'm doing it. The arguments on the cursor are correct. but instead of an AsncTask I'm using the LoaderManager now. Your code won't update automatically either. it's just a one time call.